# Quantum mechanical proof of Conway's SPIN and TWIN axioms?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I think I understand correlations of EPR-state and GHZ-state which deal with spin-1/2 particles and (-1, 1) measured values. Conway's state is spin-1 particle state with (-1, 0, 1) measured values. Which quantum mechanical state vector correspond to Conway's state? And how to prove SPIN and TWIN axioms of Conway's free will theorem from quantum mechanics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TWIN axiom just says that entanglement exists (at any distance), so it is trivial in proper quantum mechanics. The relevant entangled state is of the form
$$ |\Psi \rangle = \sum_{m=-j}^j |m\rangle \otimes |-m\rangle $$
or something of this form (phases, sign flips).

The SPIN axiom is also simple in proper quantum mechanics. It says that the eigenvalues of three operators $(J_x^2, J_y^2, J_z^2)$ will be $(0,1,1)$ or some permutation of these three numbers for some states of a physical object (a spin-one particle is enough).

It's easily realized for spin-one particles. In fact, it's enough to represent the spin as the orbital angular momentum and look at the spherical harmonics $Y_{\ell m}$ for $\ell=1$ and $m=-1$ or $0$ or $+1$.

Take $Y_{10}$, for example. It's proportional to $z=\cos\theta$ on the unit sphere. This wave function is clearly annihilated by $J_z$, the generator of the rotations around the $z$-axis. What is the action of $J_x^2$ on it? Well, we know the action of $J^2=J_x^2+J_y^2+J_z^2$ on $Y_{10}$: it is $j(j+1)\hbar^2=2\hbar^2$ times the same wave function.

A few sentences ago, we saw that $J_z$ annihilates $Y_{10}$, so the $J_z^2$ term contributes nothing. By the $x\leftrightarrow y$ reflection symmetry of $Y_{10}$, the two remaining terms $J_x^2$ and $J_y^2$ have to contribute the same i.e. one-half of $2\hbar^2  Y_{10}$ i.e. $\hbar^2 Y_{10}$. That's where the eigenvalues $(1,1)$ for $J_x^2$ and $J_y^2$ come from; the factor $\hbar^2$ was divided by or set to one (choice of units). Even though $Y_{10}$ isn't an eigenstate of $J_x$ or $J_y$, it is actually an eigenstate of their squares. This is analogous to the fact that $\cos kx$ isn't an eigenstate of $i\partial / \partial x$ but it *is* an eigenstate of $\partial^2 / \partial x^2$.

Similarly, the other two basis vectors of the 3D space of $Y_{1m}$ spherical harmonics, those proportional to $x$ or $y$ on the unit sphere (they are either the sum or the difference of $Y_{1,\pm 1}$, perhaps with phases that may change for unusual conventions), respectively, give the other two permutations of $(1,1,0)$ for the eigenvalues of $J_x^2,J_y^2,J_z^2$.

The theorem and especially its starting axioms are trivial in proper quantum mechanics. They only become non-trivial in various alternative theories people could propose instead of quantum mechanics, namely various hidden-variable theories and GRW-type collapse theories etc. The theorem shows that these hidden-variable and collapse theories cannot be made compatible with relativity.

I think that you meant Conway's *and* Kochen's axioms.